# Knockout-Validation validatedObservable is always valid when use required:{onlyIf:...}

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, single-page-application, knockout-validation

I am using [Knockout-Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) in my project.
I have model where I need to be sure that details are provided if qustion answered as yes:

```
function Model() {
    'use strict';
    var self = this;
    self.question1 = ko.observable(false);
    self.question1Details = ko.observable('');
    self.question1Details.extend({
        required: {
            onlyIf: function () { 
                return self.question1() === true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Than I use it this way:

```
var model = ko.validatedObservable(new Model());
```

But no matter what I do, model.isValid() is always true. Even if model().question1Details.isValid() is false.

I tried to specify

```
ko.validation.init({ grouping : { deep: true, observable: true }, insertMessages:true }, true);
```

But it didn't help.

Interesting thing, if I change validation rule to:

```
self.question1Details.extend({
            required: true
            }
        });
```

than it works fine. So I suspect that there is some issue with onlyIf or I am using it wrong.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  I am dealing with this now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var self=this;
self.question1 = ko.observable(false);
self.question1Details = ko.observable('');
self.question1Details.extend({
    required: {
        onlyIf: function () { return self.question1()===true;}
     }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pnr9g/1/)

Comment: Sorry this fiddle doesn't work. But it seems an answer. But why is it false if I want this field to be required only if my question answer is true? I don't get it.

Comment: Actually no, it doesn't quite work. Now it just always not valid.

Comment: sorry my mistake i have updated the fiddle and now it is working as expected.